# What does "|-" mean in a kubernetes config file

Tags: kubernetes

For example, in the following secret file(example taken from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-manually)):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  config.yaml: |-
    apiUrl: "https://my.api.com/api/v1"
    username: {{username}}
    password: {{password}}
```

What does `|-` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is Block Chomping Indicator from yaml spec.
Reference : https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534

**|-**
"strip": remove the line feed, remove the trailing blank lines from the block.